# Should I factor-out "to" in a series of infinitives?

Tags: grammaticality, infinitives, writing-style

Which of the following two forms of the sentence is better?

1. "Managers can use these findings
   to bound estimates,
   to assess the realism of road maps,
   to recognise unsustainable growth,
   to judge the health of a software development project, and
   to predict a system's hardware footprint."
2. "Managers can use these findings to
   bound estimates,
   assess the realism of road maps,
   recognise unsustainable growth,
   judge the health of a software development project, and
   predict a system's hardware footprint."

Comment: They're both grammatical. As the sentence is quite demanding, I'd personally leave in the _to_'s as partitioning markers. Though I'd probably go further and opt for bullet points.

Comment: Thank you! The sentence will appear in an article's abstract, so I have to be terse and can't use bullet points.

Answer (score 3):

The second is both more terse and more flowing- if you were reading it aloud you would find that "to" is quite an abrupt word that breaks up the flow of the text. As both are quite understandable and grammatically correct, I would go for the second.